# What is the word for sound of continuous water falling from pipes

Tags: word-request

What is the word for sound of continuous water falling. For example, Water falling on floor, through pipes may be due to overflow.

Slosh, burble, gurgle, gargle, splash and sploosh etc are few words I have searched in online dictionary, but I am unable to figure out exact word.

Comment: There is no exact word. Any single word you come up with would be subjective. The only thing that actually describes it is exactly what you've already used: *they heard **the sound of continuous water falling** from pipes.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[to drip](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/drip)

> 1. To fall in drops: Water is dripping from that leaky faucet.
> 2. To shed drops: an umbrella that is dripping all over the floor.

(American Heritage)